# Get Latest Commit URL from PyGithub Efficiently

Tags: python, git, github, pygithub

I'm using this function to get the latest commit url using [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub):

```
from github import Github

def getLastCommitURL():
    encrypted = 'mypassword'
    # naiveDecrypt defined elsewhere
    g = Github('myusername', naiveDecrypt(encrypted))
    org = g.get_organization('mycompany')
    code = org.get_repo('therepo')
    commits = code.get_commits()
    last = commits[0]
    return last.html_url
```

It works but it seems to make Github unhappy with my IP address and give me a slow response for the resulting url. Is there a more efficient way for me to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wouldn't work if you had no commits in the past 24 hours. But if you do, it seems to return faster and will request fewer commits, according to the [Github API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def getLastCommitURL():
    encrypted = 'mypassword'
    g = Github('myusername', naiveDecrypt(encrypted))
    org = g.get_organization('mycompany')
    code = org.get_repo('therepo')
    # limit to commits in past 24 hours
    since = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
    commits = code.get_commits(since=since)
    last = commits[0]
    return last.html_url
```

Answer (score 2):

You could directly make a request to the api.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

def get_latest_commit(owner, repo):
    url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits?per_page=1'.format(owner=owner, repo=repo)
    response = urlopen(url).read()
    data = json.loads(response.decode())
    return data[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    commit = get_latest_commit('mycompany', 'therepo')
    print(commit['html_url'])
```

In this case you would only being making one request to the api instead of 3 and you are only getting the last commit instead of all of them.  Should be faster as well.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for public repos, though? I don't see any authentication in your code.